# How to manage single thread job using mysql database?

Tags: mysql, single-threaded

I need to run a php a script , I want to make sure there is no more than one script running at the same time .

I am using mysql , and I though about this solution :

I build the bellow database :

```
       job_id              |  task_id | last_updated_time (AUTO UPDATE)
  "sending_emails"              77238      2107-5-3 12:2:2
```

Before running the script I create random task id , then I run a query to update the task_id .

```
 $task_id = generate_random_task_id();
    $query = "
                  UPDATE  
                         jobs  
                   SET
                         task_id = $task_id
                   WHERE
                        task_id = $task_id
                        OR
                        NOW() - last_updated_time > 30
                   LIMIT 1
             "

/*
  Then I need to check if there was an update, if yes then I will run the script otherwise i will stop since there is already another script running
*/

$query = "SELECT JOB_ID WHERE taks_id = $task_id "
$result = run($query)
if( ! isset($result[JOB_ID])){
    DIE();
}
```

is there any chance that two scripts run at the same time ?

Answer (score 0):

No, they can't run at the same time, [here's](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locks-set.html) MySQL's documentation about `UPDATE` and `SELECT`, this is what it says:

> UPDATE ... WHERE ... sets an exclusive next-key lock on every record
>   the search encounters. However, only an index record lock is required
>   for statements that lock rows using a unique index to search for a
>   unique row.

[Here's](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locking.html#innodb-shared-exclusive-locks) more about Shared and Exclusive locks:

> A shared (S) lock permits the transaction that holds the lock to read
>   a row.
>
> An exclusive (X) lock permits the transaction that holds the lock to
>   update or delete a row.
>
> If a transaction T1 holds an exclusive (X) lock on row r, a request
>   from some distinct transaction T2 for a lock of either type on r
>   cannot be granted immediately. Instead, transaction T2 has to wait for
>   transaction T1 to release its lock on row r.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there's every chance you could run the same task again.

There are two obvious solutions.

One is to open a mysql connection then acquire a lock using [GET_LOCK()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock) using a short timeout - if you acquire the lock then you're good to go. You need to maintain the db connection for the lifetime of the script.

Alternatively you could create a table with a unique contraint on finish_time, INSERT a record with a null finish time to indicate the start (it will fail if there is already a record with a null finish time) then update the finish_time to NOW() when it completes.

However using the database to represent the state of a running task only makes sense when the task is running within a lossely coupled but highly available cluster - implying that the databse is also clustered. And the nature of the clustering (NDB, asych, semi-sync, multi-master) has a lot of impact on how this will behave in practice.

OTOH if that is not the case, then using the database to represent the state is the wrong way to solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am not sure why finish_time will work, and mine will not work ?

Comment: Could you please have a look at @Darshan Mehta answer !

Comment: Leaving aside the complications of doing calculations on time in SQL without specifying the interval, your objective is only met if you can *guarantee* execution will take less than 30 seconds. There are also race conditions arising depending on your concurrency model in the database. Further, in your example you have very low entropy in your task id generation - and if you're running this with high frequency, you're going to end up with a collision at some point. Need I go on?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they can run at the same time.
If you want them to run one at a time `SELECT`
query should be changed to:

```
SELECT JOB_ID WHERE taks_id = $task_id LOCK IN SHARED MODE
```

In this case it uses a read lock.

This is the same whether you use NDB or InnoDB.